# Show the author only own types of publications. (JetEngine, Elementor)

Tags: plugins, posts, wp-query, user-roles

I created a custom post called Locations using Elementor + JetEngine. I also created a User Profile Builder Dashboard with the help of this, where the user (client) can add a location. But the problem is that for all different users, all locations from all users are available. I need them to see only their own locations.

Comment: You'll have to ask Elementor and JetEngine for how to do this, they're third party plugins and not exactly standard WP coding.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.